# How to build navigation controller from existing view controllers drew in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have built some view controllers in storyboard like in the picture below

[image]

I already implemented the data inside them, modal segue is used for transitions in between. Now I just realise when I push "back" button, previous view won't be properly loaded. I figure I should switch to navigation controller and add those controllers in stack instead. But I don't know how to go from where I am now.

I think I should make changes programmatically because I found building navigation controller in storyboard won't have much variation in UI design (at least I don't know how to implement existing pages in that way). So what should I do to implement programmatically? Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select Category View Controller and go to menu: Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. Then change segues style from Modal to Push.

Comment: and remove your back buttons also

Comment: That's what I worried, I need to have those back buttons. So is there any way to get rid of the navigation bar introduced by your method? thanks.

Comment: Ok I have figured it out thanks! Just use [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:Yes] will do. Thanks for your help!